# Retrieve MySQL records where date is X day ago

Tags: mysql, date

Hello i am trying to pull some record from MySQL DB, i've tried may solution here such as:

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.reference, o.id_customer, DATE_FORMAT(o.invoice_date, '%m%d%y') AS 'invoice_date'
FROM ps_orders AS o
WHERE DATE(o.invoice_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 100 DAY;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.reference, o.id_customer, o.invoice_date
FROM ps_orders AS o
WHERE o.invoice_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

But i keep getting 0 result.

The format of:

```
o.invoice_date
```

is 2013-04-06 02:02:12 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS).

I am not sure why i keep getting 0 result. When i try with this query:

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.reference, o.id_customer, o.invoice_date
FROM ps_orders AS o
WHERE o.invoice_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
ORDER BY o.invoice_date DESC;
```

it **works**, but i only want to get the data from **x DAY ago (EXACTLY)**. Can someone point me to the right direction. Thanks for the help...

Comment: `DATE(o.invoice_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 100 DAY` should be fine even if it won't take advantage of an index ... are you sure you have invoices 100 days ago?

Comment: @fthiella yes, i tried with different numbers e.g 30, 40, 10, 100 yet still getting 0 result. Not sure why.

Comment: @fthiella, on second thought you are right. I don't have invoice 100 days ago (exactly).

Comment: create a dummy invoice with the date 30 days ago and try your query again it should work. other than that gordons solutions should work as well

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is:

```
WHERE o.invoice_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND
      o.invoice_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY
```

This allows the query engine to use an index on `o.invoice_date`.